# Delete Azure resources or resource groups using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I write a Powershell script that deletes all resources and all resource groups excluding selected resources and resource groups in a given Azure subscription?

I wrote such a script:

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId (hidden by me)

```
             $excludedResourceGroups = @("rgGrzesiek1")
             $excludedResources = @("webapp1")
            
             $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -notin $excludedResourceGroups }

             foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
                 $resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object {$.Name -notin $excludedResources }
                 foreach ($resource in $resources) {
                    Remove-AzResource -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -Force
                 }
             }
             foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
                    Remove-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Force
```

After applying this script as an 'inlinescript' in the pipeline, all resources remain in the resource group "rgGrzesiek1".

I need that in the resource group named "rgGrzesiek1" only 1 resource named: "webapp1".

Greetings and looking forward to help.

Please check the script and show me where the error is in the script.

Comment: Your script is excluding from the list of resource groups, so you're then never retrieving a list of resources from rgGrzesiek1

Comment: First, Why do you want to even achieve this in a single script? Its better to remove the resource groups which you don't want to have then work on resource groups where you want to keep few resources.